# Root of a complex number - sign

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

In the case of the square root of a negative real (say, the discriminant in a quadratic equation), there are considered both signs of the square root with 'i' (denoting the imaginary quantity) being outside the radical, i.e. $ x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm i\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$.

But for a complex quantity inside the square root, the negative sign is ignored, as it is stated that the complex quantity's square root will generate both the negative and positive quantities. So, for solving a quadratic equation with complex number as the discriminant, the roots are stated as $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$.

I am confused by the latter statement about the complex number, and also want a generalization for any root value, say cube root of a complex number, and so on.

Comment: If you are following a syllabus recommending to use the notation $$\sqrt{z}$$ for $z$ complex, not real nonnegative, well... I can only express my sympathy, but you might try to get some more serious sources on the subject.

Comment: Do you know how to derive the quadratic formula? Do it while keeping in mind that the numbers you're working on are complex, and I hope you'll find that the answer will come to you.

Comment: @Did: Thanks for insight into the symbols used for that case. I hope that you meant that square root symbol is not meant for complex quantity. If not, please indicate more.

Comment: ?? Why do you hypothetize that I would be meaning something else than what is written in my comment?

Comment: @Arthur: It is easy to derive it, given the equation $ax^2 + bx + c$ =>
 $(x^2 + \dfrac{b}{a} + \dfrac{b^2}{4a^2}$) = $\frac {b^2}{4a^2} -\dfrac{c}{a}$ => $(x+\dfrac{b}{2a})^2$=$\dfrac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$. Now this leads to the quadratic form. If any of the term a, b, or c is imaginary the discriminant is imaginary. But, it doesn't go further than that in terms of realizing the answer.

Comment: @Did: So, only form possible is $(complex-value)^\dfrac{1}{2} $ in that case. But, I have example of a standard text (Allan Jeffrey, Complex Analysis and Applications, 2nd edn., page #20, 21) that uses usual square root symbol for imaginary quantity as discriminant.

Comment: No, this is just another horror... But I am surprised, didn't you read @MPW's post below?

Comment: In the end, there is no ambiguity if you write "$\pm\sqrt{\Delta}$" since both roots are encompassed. Dropping the "$\pm$" is not good for complex $\Delta$ since that *is* ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that, when $x\in[0,+\infty)$, the symbol $\sqrt x$ means the only square root of $x$ which belongs to $[0,+\infty)$. So, if we want to talk about *both* square roots of $x$, we must mention $\sqrt x$ and $-\sqrt x$,

However, if $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,+\infty)$, there is no standard choice among the square roots of $x$. So, the symbol $\sqrt x$ may mean *any* square root of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer, though I am not the OP. But, may I ask you what the backslash mark mean after complex space letter? :)

Comment: The expression $A\setminus B$ means $\{a\in A\mid a\notin B\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, sir.
Then, does $x \notin A \setminus B$ mean the opposite, which is $\{\, a \in B ∣ a \notin A \,\}$?

Comment: That depends upon the context. If $A=[0,3]$, $B=[0,1]$, and we are working on $\Bbb R$, then $x\notin A\setminus B$ means that $x$ is a real number which does not belong to $A\setminus B=(1,3]$.

Comment: Thank you very much, again for the answer. Aha, then it means $A \setminus B$ part is evaluated before '$\in$' sign. :)

Comment: I wish you a good day.

Answer (score 2):

That statement is really inaccurate. To be more precise, it is a fact that every nonzero complex number (including all nonzero reals) has exactly two square roots, and they are opposites.

They are square roots in the sense that their squares are both equal to the given nonzero complex number. We often avoid using the symbol "$\sqrt{\cdot}$" in this context since it is no longer natural which root should be assigned to that symbol. But if you do decide which root is $\sqrt{z}$, the other root is always $-\sqrt{z}$.